# Python re doesn't match last capture group

Tags: python, regex, capture-group

For the following code:

```
t1 = 'tyler vs ryan'
p1 = re.compile('(.*?) vs (.*?)')
print p1.findall(t1)
```

the output is:

```
[('tyler', '')]
```

but I would've expected this:

```
[('tyler', 'ryan')]
```

---

I have found that if I add a delimiter I can get it to work:

```
t2 = 'tyler vs ryan!'               # Notice the exclamation mark
p2 = re.compile('(.*?) vs (.*?)!')  # Notice the exclamation mark
print p2.findall(t2)
```

outputs:

```
[('tyler', 'ryan')]
```

---

Is there a way I can get my matches without having a custom delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Try this

```
t1 = 'tyler vs ryan'
p1 = re.compile('(.*?) vs (.*?)$') 
print p1.findall(t1)
```

gives:

```
[('tyler', 'ryan')]
```

$ - Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline.

Answer (score 4):

`(.*?)` is non greedy it will match the smallest it can which is the empty string (after the `vs` at least)

try `(.*)` or `([^ ]*)` or something

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarifying the non-greedy matching, however for my purposes @Simon's answer is better.

Answer (score 3):

The regex is capturing the shortest string it can; that's what the question mark signifies. So as soon as it has captured the text `vs` it captures an empty string, then stops. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Direct link: https://regex101.com/r/hO4lM7/2

If you use:

`re.compile('(.*?) vs (.*)')`

that is, without the 2nd question mark, it will capture the text after `vs` as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are assured of single-name combatants, you could use a regex like:

```
r'\s*(\S+)\s*vs\s*(\S+)\s*'
```

Your use of findall() implies to me you're expecting to have to match multiple pairings - if not, then you may want to use search() and use the `^` and `$` regex special characters to more tightly bound your search.

Answer (score 0):

The non greedy `?`is preventing to capture te second word. It would be better to do

```
r'(.*) vs (.*)'
```